# Узнать текущее событие проходящие на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать текущие события которые происходят на странице

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов:

```
$(document).on("click",function(event){
    console.log(event.target.nodeName+" clicked");
});
```

Comment: Ваш код отработает только при клике.
А мне нужен снипет который будет отображать в консоли названия событий происходящие на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что никак, кроме как перечесление всех событий и подписка на них. Мне кажется что вы делаете что то не так и можно придумать более простое решение, может быть осветите более подробно задачу?